# Not visible and searchable Polish characters

Tags: sql, plsql, character-encoding, nls-lang

I have a question to you.

I have table where I'm saving names of groups and I can save name with polish characters but this saving like this:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Zarny |

When my name is `Żarny`.
And when I do select something like this

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM this_table 
 WHERE name = 'Zarny'
```

or

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM this_table 
 WHERE name = 'Żarny'
```

it returns me totally nothing.

Do you have any idea what can I do?

Comment: First of all, check whether `POLISH` returns from `SELECT value FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_LANGUAGE'`. Otherwise you should consult your DBA.

Comment: Yea, its return for me 'POLISH'. I dont really know what to do or what can I check. Im a DBA becouse its my private database so I don't have anyone who can help me.

Comment: Check also if `NLS_TERRITORY`'s value is `POLAND`

Answer (score 0):

I find the response for my question.
I need to set in regedit polish language.
In *Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE* Im set the `POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250`.